# In a shell script, how to echo shell commands as they are executed to standard output (not standard error)?

Tags: linux, shell, cron

I want to write a simple cron job wrapper extending the native cron in following ways:

1. It only sends email when a job print something to standard error or a job's return code is not 0.
2. It logs all commands executed (and their output) to a log file.

Here's my problem, I want all commands executed in cron job get logged (bullet #2 above), but `/bin/bash -x job.sh` (or `set -x` inside `job.sh`) would trigger the alert email (breaking bullet #1 above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `bash(1)` man page:

> BASH_XTRACEFD
>
> If  set  to an integer corresponding to a valid file descriptor,
>                 **bash** will write the  trace  output  generated  when  `set -x`  is
>                 enabled  to that file descriptor.  The file descriptor is closed
>                 when **BASH_XTRACEFD** is unset or assigned a new value.   Unsetting
>                 **BASH_XTRACEFD**  or assigning it the empty string causes the trace
>                 output to be sent to the  standard  error.   Note  that  setting
>                 **BASH_XTRACEFD** to 2 (the standard error file descriptor) and then
>                 unsetting it will result in the standard error being closed.

...

```
BASH_XTRACEFD=1
set -x
```